# The this scope of nodejs middlewares when using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to create a upload middleware for my nodejs server app.

I am using typescript:

```
/// <reference path="./Scripts/typings/express/express.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./Scripts/typings/async/async.d.ts" />

import file = module('modules/fileupload_file');
import async = module('async');

export class FileUpload {
    private uploadDelegate: any;

    constructor(options) {
        this.uploadDelegate = options.adapter || new file.filesystem(options);
        console.log(this.uploadDelegate);
    }

    middleware(req: ExpressServerRequest, res: ExpressServerResponse, next) {
        if (typeof req.files === 'undefined' || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
          return next()
        }

        async.each( Object.keys(req.files), (field, cb) => {
            var files = req.files[field],
                filesArray = [];

            if (!Array.isArray(files))
                files = [files];

            async.each(files, (file, cb1) => {
                filesArray = [];

                if (typeof file.path === 'undefined' || file.size === 0) {
                    return cb1(null);

                }
                console.log(this);
                this.uploadDelegate.put(file, function (error, storedFile) {
                    filesArray.push(storedFile);
                    cb1(null);
                });

            }, (err: string) => {     
                console.log(err);
                console.log(field);           
                console.log(filesArray);

                req.body[field] = filesArray;
                cb(null);

            });
        }, next);
    }
}
```

this turns into:

```
var file = require("./modules/fileupload_file");
var async = require('async');

var FileUpload = (function () {
    function FileUpload(options) {
        this.uploadDelegate = options.adapter || new file.filesystem(options);
        console.log(this.uploadDelegate);
    }
    FileUpload.prototype.middleware = function (req, res, next) {
        var _this = this;
        if (typeof req.files === 'undefined' || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
            return next();
        }

        async.each(Object.keys(req.files), function (field, cb) {
            var files = req.files[field], filesArray = [];

            if (!Array.isArray(files))
                files = [files];

            async.each(files, function (file, cb1) {
                filesArray = [];

                if (typeof file.path === 'undefined' || file.size === 0) {
                    return cb1(null);
                }
                console.log(_this);
                _this.uploadDelegate.put(file, function (error, storedFile) {
                    filesArray.push(storedFile);
                    cb1(null);
                });
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(field);
                console.log(filesArray);

                req.body[field] = filesArray;
                cb(null);
            });
        }, next);
    };
    return FileUpload;
})();
exports.FileUpload = FileUpload;
```

using it like this:

```
app.post('/job/:name', myupload_middleware, function (req, res) {
```

my problem are now that i get:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'put' of undefined
```

in the line: `_this.uploadDelegate.put(file, function (error, storedFile) {`

in the constructer i see that this.uploadDelegate have been set.
The console.log(_this) tells me that the this scope is not what i expects it to be?

```
{ ArrayBuffer: [Function: ArrayBuffer],
  Int8Array: { [Function: Int8Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 1 },
  Uint8Array: { [Function: Uint8Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 1 },
  Uint8ClampedArray: { [Function: Uint8ClampedArray] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 1 },
  Int16Array: { [Function: Int16Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 2 },
  Uint16Array: { [Function: Uint16Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 2 },
  Int32Array: { [Function: Int32Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 4 },
  Uint32Array: { [Function: Uint32Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 4 },
  Float32Array: { [Function: Float32Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 4 },
  Float64Array: { [Function: Float64Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 8 },
  DataView: [Function: DataView],
  DTRACE_NET_SERVER_CONNECTION: [Function],
  DTRACE_NET_STREAM_END: [Function],
  DTRACE_NET_SOCKET_READ: [Function],
  DTRACE_NET_SOCKET_WRITE: [Function],
  DTRACE_HTTP_SERVER_REQUEST: [Function],
  DTRACE_HTTP_SERVER_RESPONSE: [Function],
  DTRACE_HTTP_CLIENT_REQUEST: [Function],
  DTRACE_HTTP_CLIENT_RESPONSE: [Function],
  COUNTER_NET_SERVER_CONNECTION: [Function],
  COUNTER_NET_SERVER_CONNECTION_CLOSE: [Function],
  COUNTER_HTTP_SERVER_REQUEST: [Function],
  COUNTER_HTTP_SERVER_RESPONSE: [Function],
  COUNTER_HTTP_CLIENT_REQUEST: [Function],
  COUNTER_HTTP_CLIENT_RESPONSE: [Function],
  global: [Circular],
  process:
   { title: 'Administrator: Node.js command prompt - node  app.js',
     version: 'v0.10.12',
     moduleLoadList:
      [ 'Binding evals',
        'Binding natives',
        'NativeModule events',
        'NativeModule buffer',
        'Binding buffer',
        'NativeModule assert',
        'NativeModule util',
        'NativeModule path',
        'NativeModule module',
        'NativeModule fs',
        'Binding fs',
        'Binding constants',
        'NativeModule stream',
        'NativeModule _stream_readable',
        'NativeModule _stream_writable',
        'NativeModule _stream_duplex',
        'NativeModule _stream_transform',
        'NativeModule _stream_passthrough',
        'NativeModule http',
        'NativeModule net',
        'NativeModule timers',
        'Binding timer_wrap',
        'NativeModule _linklist',
        'Binding cares_wrap',
        'NativeModule url',
        'NativeModule punycode',
        'NativeModule querystring',
        'NativeModule freelist',
        'Binding http_parser',
        'NativeModule crypto',
        'Binding crypto',
        'NativeModule string_decoder',
        'NativeModule tty',
        'Binding tty_wrap',
        'NativeModule zlib',
        'Binding zlib',
        'NativeModule os',
        'Binding os',
        'NativeModule console',
        'Binding signal_wrap',
        'Binding tcp_wrap',
        'NativeModule cluster',
        'NativeModule child_process',
        'NativeModule dgram',
        'Binding udp_wrap',
        'Binding process_wrap' ],
     versions:
      { http_parser: '1.0',
        node: '0.10.12',
        v8: '3.14.5.9',
        ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
        uv: '0.10.11',
        zlib: '1.2.3',
        modules: '11',
        openssl: '1.0.1e' },
     arch: 'x64',
     platform: 'win32',
     argv:
      [ 'node',
        'D:\\GitHub\\unix-node-js-samples\\AzureHelloWorld\\app.js' ],
     execArgv: [],
     env:
      { ALLUSERSPROFILE: 'C:\\ProgramData',
        AMDAPPSDKROOT: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD APP\\',
        APPDATA: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming',
        CommonProgramFiles: 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files',
        'CommonProgramFiles(x86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files',
        CommonProgramW6432: 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files',
        COMPUTERNAME: 'SERVER-PC',
        ComSpec: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe',
        FP_NO_HOST_CHECK: 'NO',
        HOMEDRIVE: 'C:',
        HOMEPATH: '\\Users\\Administrator',
        LOCALAPPDATA: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local',
        LOGONSERVER: '\\\\SERVER-PC',
        NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: '8',
        OS: 'Windows_NT',
        Path: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Program Files
\\nodejs\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD APP\\bin\\x86_64;C:\\Program Files (x86)
\\AMD APP\\bin\\x86;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbe
m;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ATI
Technologies\\ATI.ACE\\Core-Static;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft ASP.NET\\A
SP.NET Web Pages\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\Tools\\Bi
nn\\;C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2012b\\runtime\\win64;C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB
\\R2012b\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\Web Platform Installer\\;C:\\Program
 Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\TypeScript\\;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Users
\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm',
        PATHEXT: '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC',
        PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: 'AMD64',
        PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5, GenuineInte
l',
        PROCESSOR_LEVEL: '6',
        PROCESSOR_REVISION: '1a05',
        ProgramData: 'C:\\ProgramData',
        ProgramFiles: 'C:\\Program Files',
        'ProgramFiles(x86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)',
        ProgramW6432: 'C:\\Program Files',
        PROMPT: '$P$G',
        PSModulePath: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\
;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows Azure\\PowerShell\\',
        PUBLIC: 'C:\\Users\\Public',
        SESSIONNAME: 'Console',
        SSH_AGENT_PID: '5316',
        SSH_AUTH_SOCK: '/tmp/ssh-aTYruZ5256/agent.5256',
        SystemDrive: 'C:',
        SystemRoot: 'C:\\Windows',
        TEMP: 'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1',
        TMP: 'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1',
        USERDOMAIN: 'SERVER-PC',
        USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: 'SERVER-PC',
        USERNAME: 'Administrator',
        USERPROFILE: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator',
        VS110COMNTOOLS: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\
Common7\\Tools\\',
        windir: 'C:\\Windows' },
     pid: 7776,
     features:
      { debug: false,
        uv: true,
        ipv6: true,
        tls_npn: true,
        tls_sni: true,
        tls: true },
     _needImmediateCallback: false,
     execPath: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
     debugPort: 5858,
     _getActiveRequests: [Function],
     _getActiveHandles: [Function],
     _needTickCallback: [Function],
     reallyExit: [Function],
     abort: [Function],
     chdir: [Function],
     cwd: [Function],
     umask: [Function],
     _kill: [Function],
     _debugProcess: [Function],
     _debugPause: [Function],
     _debugEnd: [Function],
     hrtime: [Function],
     dlopen: [Function],
     uptime: [Function],
     memoryUsage: [Function],
     binding: [Function],
     _usingDomains: [Function],
     _tickInfoBox: { '0': 0, '1': 0, '2': 0 },
     _events: { SIGWINCH: [Function] },
     domain: null,
     _maxListeners: 10,
     EventEmitter: { [Function: EventEmitter] listenerCount: [Function] },
     _fatalException: [Function],
     _exiting: false,
     assert: [Function],
     config: { target_defaults: [Object], variables: [Object] },
     nextTick: [Function: nextTick],
     _nextDomainTick: [Function: _nextDomainTick],
     _tickCallback: [Function: _tickCallback],
     _tickDomainCallback: [Function: _tickDomainCallback],
     _tickFromSpinner: [Function: _tickFromSpinner],
     maxTickDepth: 1000,
     stdout: [Getter],
     stderr: [Getter],
     stdin: [Getter],
     openStdin: [Function],
     exit: [Function],
     kill: [Function],
     addListener: [Function],
     on: [Function],
     removeListener: [Function],
     mainModule:
      { id: '.',
        exports: {},
        parent: null,
        filename: 'D:\\GitHub\\unix-node-js-samples\\AzureHelloWorld\\app.js',
        loaded: true,
        children: [Object],
        paths: [Object] },
     _immediateCallback: [Function: processImmediate],
     _errno: 'EALREADY' },
  GLOBAL: [Circular],
  root: [Circular],
  Buffer:
   { [Function: Buffer]
     isEncoding: [Function],
     poolSize: 8192,
     isBuffer: [Function: isBuffer],
     byteLength: [Function],
     concat: [Function],
     _charsWritten: 38 },
  setTimeout: [Function],
  setInterval: [Function],
  clearTimeout: [Function],
  clearInterval: [Function],
  setImmediate: [Function],
  clearImmediate: [Function],
  console: [Getter] }
```

Comment: I would set a breakpoint on console.log(_this); and look at the stacktrace.  It looks like your function is being called with apply, call or bind to change the meaning of this.  Maybe you can figure out why.

Comment: Hi. Have u figured out why this it happening. I have the same problem.thanks

Comment: Sorry, long time since i worked with it and dont really recall. But the answer to the post seems corrent to what i have learned with typescript since than.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using arrow functions preserves the meaning of `this`.

You are using an arrow function here:

```
async.each( Object.keys(req.files), (field, cb) => {
```

If you don't want to preserve the scope of `this`, use a standard function instead:

```
async.each( Object.keys(req.files), function (field, cb) {
```

You'll see that the `_this` variable in the compiled JavaScript will disappear when you do this.

If you want both meanings, you can manually store the context...

```
var _self = this;
async.each( Object.keys(req.files), function (field, cb) {
    // self is the "outer this"
    // this is the "inner this"
```

Comment: Here's a great explanation of the problem, the possible solutions and the tradeoffs to consider: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript