# Typescript express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I have a  simple auth middleware for express. It checks header and if all cool it calls next()

Now when i am in "DoSomething" "this" is equal to global and not the  instance of "Test"  and
"this.DoSomeThingPrivate" is undefined.

I have tried the

```
DoSomeThingPrivate :() => void;

this.DoSomeThingPrivate = () => {
...
}
```

pattern. But also does not work.

```
import express = require('express');

var app = express();

class Test {    
    constructor() {        
    }

    DoSomething(req:express.Request, res:express.Response, next:Function) :void {       
        this.DoSomeThingPrivate();
    }

    private DoSomeThingPrivate() :void
    {       
    }
}

var test = new Test();

app.use(test.DoSomething);
```

[Relates to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263076/the-this-scope-of-nodejs-middlewares-when-using-typescript)

Any Ideas...

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've passed a reference just to the function itself. The function's instance will be global. You need to bind the function to the instance of `test`.

```
app.use(test.DoSomething.bind(test));
```

Comment: thanks dude that worked. I am still getting use to typescript

Comment: No worries. That's not a Typescript specific problem though. You'll find that happens generally in JavaScript.

Comment: In addition to this answer and @basarat's answer, here's [a great description of 'this' in TypeScript][1] which describes the cause of the problem, the solutions offered here and the tradeoffs when choosing one of them.

  [1]: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript

Comment: An important argument for the double fat arrow syntax `DoSomething = (...params...) => { ...function contents...}` versus `.bind` is that double arrow is typesafe in TypeScript.

Answer (score 20):

The following should work fine i.e. use fat arrow for `DoSomething` not `DoSomethingPrivate`:

```
import * as express from 'express';

var app = express();

class Test {    
    constructor() {        
    }

    // important: 
    DoSomething = (req:express.Request, res:express.Response, next:express.NextFunction) => {       
        this.DoSomeThingPrivate();
    }

    private DoSomeThingPrivate() :void
    {       
    }
}

var test = new Test();

app.use(test.DoSomething);
```

**Note:** You should not need to use `bind`. Also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: you can also use type `express.NextFunction` for `next` param.

Comment: I think this approach is considerably better thant `bind`.

Comment: You can let the compiler infer the parameters types by typing `DoSomething` like so: `DoSomething: express.RequestHandler = (req, res, next) => ...`